# Is there an execution order sequence in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, future

I have a problem and I want to save data from my website. This data should only be transferred if the phone number was transferred. But the program I wrote does not go through from bottom to top and I get the error message "Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '[]' was called on null."
In the debugger I saw that after the "if (!await MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission)" it goes directly into the widget build where it tries to display _loadHtml which is not ready yet. Is there a way to change the order of the futures in Flutter or is there a better solution to solve this problem?

```
Future<void> getDataFromServer() async {
    final responsew = await initMobilNumberState();
    final response = await _fetchSampleData();

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      Map<String, dynamic> data = json.decode(response.body);
      _list = data.values.toList();
    } else {
      // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
      // then throw an exception.
      showAlertNoInternet(context);
      print('Failed to load data from server');
    }
  }

  Future<http.Response> _fetchSampleData() async {
    String s = _mobileNumber;
    print(s);
    return http.get('http://test-site' + _mobileNumber);
  }

  Future<void> initMobilNumberState() async {
    if (!await MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission) {
      await MobileNumber.requestPhonePermission;
      return;
    }
    String mobileNumber = '';

    try {
      mobileNumber = await MobileNumber.mobileNumber;
      _simCard = await MobileNumber.getSimCards;
    } on PlatformException catch (e) {
      debugPrint("Failed to get mobile number because of '${e.message}'");
    }

    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      var re = RegExp(r'\+[^]*');
      _mobileNumber = mobileNumber.replaceRange(0, 3, ''.replaceAll(re, '+'));
    });
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String _loadHtml(String) {
      return r'''
''' +
          _list[1][0] +
          '''
</body>
</html>
''';
    }

    String _loadHtml2(String) {
      var foo = '';
      for (int i = 0; i < _list[0].length; i++) {
        foo += r'''
          ''' +
            _list[0][i] +
            '''
          </body>
          </html>
          ''';
      }

      return foo;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(35, 31, 32, 1),
        actions: <Widget>[
          NavigationControls(_controller.future),
        ],
      ),
      body: Builder(builder: (BuildContext context) {

        return WebView(
          initialUrl:

              new Uri.dataFromString(_loadHtml(String), mimeType: 'text/html')
                      .toString() +
                  _loadHtml2(String),

          ///
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
            _controller.complete(webViewController);
          },
          javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
            _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
          ].toSet(),

          navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
            for (int i = 0; i < _list[2].length; i++) {
              if (request.url.startsWith(_list[2][i])) {
                print('allowing navigation to $request}');
                return NavigationDecision.navigate; //prevent

              }
            }
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          },
          onPageStarted: (String url) {
            print('Page started loading: $url');
          },
          onPageFinished: (String url) {
            print('Page finished loading: $url');
          },
          gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
        );
      }),
    );
  }
```

Update:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String _loadHtml(String) {
      return r'''
''' +
          _list[1][0] +
          '''
</body>
</html>
''';
    }

    String _loadHtml2(String) {
      var foo = '';
      for (int i = 0; i < _list[0].length; i++) {
        foo += r'''
          ''' +
            _list[0][i] +
            '''
          </body>
          </html>
          ''';
      }

      return foo;
    }

    FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: getDataFromServer(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return WebView(
            initialUrl:

                /// Hier werden die HTML Strings eingelesen und als Website angezeigt.
                new Uri.dataFromString(_loadHtml(String), mimeType: 'text/html')
                        .toString() +
                    _loadHtml2(String),

            ///
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
            onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
              _controller.complete(webViewController);
            },
            javascriptChannels: <JavascriptChannel>[
              _toasterJavascriptChannel(context),
            ].toSet(),

            /// In der [navigationDelegate] wird die WhiteList durch einen for loop durchgeangen.
            navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
              for (int i = 0; i < _list[2].length; i++) {
                if (request.url.startsWith(_list[2][i])) {
                  print('allowing navigation to $request}');
                  return NavigationDecision.navigate; //prevent

                }
              }
              return NavigationDecision.prevent;
            },
            onPageStarted: (String url) {
              print('Page started loading: $url');
            },
            onPageFinished: (String url) {
              print('Page finished loading: $url');
            },
            gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
          );
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the statement:

```
if (!await MobileNumber.hasPhonePermission)
```

This statement is an asynchronous statement i.e. while it completes, the control goes on to the next statement, and the if condition resorts to false since the await statement has returned null for the time being.
A better solution would be to use a future builder for such async statements and display a progress indicator while waiting for the completion of async tasks.

Comment: Okay thank your for your answer @Nandan Wewhare. What could it look like in my example ? Sorry for the stupid question but I have never worked with a future Builder before.

Comment: give it a search how to use future builder in flutter, there are many answers already exists, one thing in flutter is you cant wait for the data to arrive before creating the UI, but you can update the UI once the data arrives

Comment: @Yadu Okay I tried but I keep getting error messages. It is reloaded but something is wrong.

Comment: a list or a iterable you are using is null, on which line does the error being thrown

Comment: @MarcelK checkout this link: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html. I highly recommend watching the video of widget of the week.